# how to delete files in folder with thousands of files

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, logs, rm

in  the folder

```
cd /var/log/hive
```

I guess we have thundered of log files

I say that because

if I do under this folder

```
ls -l
```

then its stuck and only CNTRL C , will exit

so I cant to vew all files

in this case how to tryng to delete the files or the old files

or what we can do else ?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked many times earlier, however: use `find ... -delete` where the "..." part selects what files to remove.

Comment: you could try `echo *` as that just globs the filenames and doesn't need to retrieve details like size/timestamp/etc and sort them; that'll at least show you how many files are in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete files (and folders) older than n days, you can use:

```
find /var/log/hive -mindepth 1 -mtime +n -delete
```

Note: Run without the `-delete` first to see what would be deleted.

Comment: Bear in mind that this will remove anything in any subdirectories of `hive` also.  Best to use `-print` first _without_ `-delete` so that you can review what is found _before_ it is removed.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Added a cautionary note. Is `-print` necessary ?

Comment: we get find: unknown predicate `-min-depth'

Comment: @yael My bad, it should be `-mindepth`

Comment: `-print` is the default, but I generally prefer to explicitly invoke what I wish to do, as that makes it easier to change to something else when iterating or maintaining the script(s) involved.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend of what you mean when you say old; if you want to list (for example) the files that have been modified thest last 2 days (2 days as an example) you can play with the find comand by this way:

`ls  |find -mtime -2`

Where **mtime** would refer to the files/directories that have been modified the last two days.

Otherwise there is no way to check the "creation time" of the file, unless you have  named with an informative name to the log files; names such as log_date; in that case you can play with a grep in order to show you the wished result.

As we are talking about logs, is better to store them (and check the necessary ones) instead of deleting them.

Comment: I don't think `ls |` does anything here, does it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, without it it would be valid also; it would be more "accurate" with `find /var/log/hive -mtime -2`.